# How to plot an error band with weighted data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, seaborn

Seaborn is a beautiful package that let's me plot data from DataFrames, with automatic error band.

Seaborn calculates the average and the deviation when the dataframe holds multiple y values for an x value. But what if the data in my DataFrame is weighted? Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'x' : [1, 2, 3, 4]*3,   # 3 sets of same x values
    'y' : [1.5, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 0.9, 1.9, 2.9, 3.9, 1, 2, 3, 4], # 3 sets of slightly different y values
    'w' : [100] + [0.1]*11   # weights
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)

sns.lineplot(data, x='x', y='y')
plt.show()
```

Here seaborn will take the unweighted values for x and y. Is there a neat way to take the column 'w' into account when taking the average?

I've taken a look at `estimator` argument of `lineplot`, but a function passed under this argument does not appear to have access to the weight column.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: A possible workaround is to repeat the x and y values depending on the weights. With fractional weights, they need to be multiplied by a large enough value, because repetition factors need to be integers.  In the given example, you would repeat the first value 1000 times, and use the others just once.  When the repetitions create too many values, the factors might need to be reduced. Sometimes rounding might be needed.

Comment: See also [How to use a weighted mean estimator in seaborn factor plot (incl bootstrapping)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771520/how-to-use-a-weighted-mean-estimator-in-seaborn-factor-plot-incl-bootstrapping) for a different type of workarround.